# How to return an array with var_export

Tags: php

I have this:

```
$custom = var_export('return ' . self::$push_action['custom']($data), true);
```

This will call this method:

```
protected static function match($data) {
    $match = service::$db->select('matches', 'match_id', array('user_id' => $data['user_id'], 'opponent_id' => $data['opponent_id']), 'ORDER BY match_id DESC LIMIT 1');
    return array('match_id' => $match[0]['match_id']);
}
```

But I am getting this error:

```
Notice:  Array to string conversion in....
```

How do I return the array correctly from the `match($data)` method?

I need the variable `$custom` to be filled with the returned array.

Thanks for any help

Comment: `$custom = 'return ' . var_export(self::$push_action['custom']($data), true) . ';';`? It's not quite clear why you are using var_export, because that will turn the array into a string.

Comment: @DCoder No errors but still the $custom var is empty

Comment: @DiegoPucci You get the notice because you're concatenating a string and array together. The returned value in your case should be `return Array`. It can't be empty. Not in the example you are showing.

Answer (score 0):

basically you can't use `var_export` to return an Array ([var_export DOC](http://php.net/var_export))

> Outputs or returns a parsable string representation of a variable

Answer (score 0):

According to description:

```
$custom = self::$push_action['custom']($data);
```

If you want to export data to file and later read it to $custom than:

**Write to file "foo.php":**

```
$fileContent = 'return ' . var_export(self::$push_action['custom']($data), true) . ';';
file_put_contents('foo.php', $fileContent);
```

**Read from file "foo.php" to $custom:**

```
$custom = include 'foo.php"
```